# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FOR'

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have written the query mentioned below...

```
    DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(Name)  
                    from dbo.[WorkflowInstanceParameter] 
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')


Go 
set @query = 'SELECT ' + @cols + ' 
            from 
            (
                select wi.Id,wip.Name, wip.stringValue
                from FROM [ESP2_DEV1].[dbo].[WorkflowInstanceParameter] wip,
 [WorkflowParameterGroupInstance] wpgi, [ESP2_DEV1].[dbo].[WorkflowInstance] wi,
 dbo.WorkflowDefinition wd
 where wip.[WorkflowParameterGroupInstanceId] = wpgi.id
 and wpgi.[WorkflowInstanceId] =wi.id and
  wi.workflowDefinitionId=wd.id
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(stringValue)
                for Name in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

but it is failing with error "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FOR'"

Can anyone help me this?????

Comment: Show us entire query .Your missing `Select` at the beginning

Comment: Kindly see the updates

Comment: That updated version will never work. Variables do not survive across separate batches (i.e. `GO`)

Comment: Thanks for letting me know this.....do we have any alternative for this....I tried with removing Go...but still failing with erro "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'"

Comment: So the error is shifting to different locations? (Question says `FOR`, now in your comment you say `FROM`)

Comment: Yes....now the error is changed but on the same stuff function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The keyword FROM is repeated in the set @query clause:

```
select wi.Id,wip.Name, wip.stringValue
            from FROM [ESP2_DEV1].[dbo].[WorkflowInstanceParameter] wip
```

Comment: Yes...you are right....Sorry for bothering you on this....Thanks for your help....

Answer (score 6):

This isn't really an answer for this post but if you google this error its one of the top hits.

I was running into this problem because I was trying to name a cursor with @

```
declare @someName cursor for
```

this doesnt work.

You need to do:

```
declare someName cursor for
```

instead.

I'm not clear if this is always the case as I've seen plenty of examples online which use @ and plenty which dont which is confusing.  I'm new to sqlserver so not sure if there is something subtle going on here.  However this definitely fixed the error in my case.  This point seems to not be documented much online, however [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5491181/syntax-error-on-sql-server) documents it but was much harder to find on google for some reason!

Funny thing to force on names!  I'm convertinig an oracle schema to sqlserver and had to add @ to variables everywhere but not these ones apparently!  I guess the guys who did cursors missed that meeting or something!